# Get attribute of specific index object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am trying to iterate through two array in my view in Angular2. I iterate through my first array using `*ngFor` and I use the index to iterate through the second one. The problem is, I can't get the attribute of an object of the second array, it's just bug everything.

```
<tr *ngFor="let round of rounds ; let i = index">
   <td>{{customers[i].login}}</td>
   <td>{{round.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here, the `customers[i].login` doesn't work. But if instead I put only `customers[i]` I'll see in my view that I have `[object Object]`.

How can I access the attribute of my customer object, or how can I iterate through the two array at the same time in a better way ?

Comment: Can you try `customers[i]?.login`?

Comment: Perfect ! What is the ? used for ? (if you want you can make an answer and explain it quickly, so we can put the question as answered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
customers[i]?.login
```

You can use the `?.` accessor in order to prevent the error from happening.

> The accessor variant of the existential operator ?. can be used to
>   soak up null references in a chain of properties. Use it instead of
>   the dot accessor . in cases where the base value may be null or
>   undefined.